# R crashed when plotting Lidar points with lidR

Tags: r, plot, lidr

I had to re-downloaded the latest R and Rstudio with all previous packages deleted...
Now I cannot plot 3D Lidar points with the lidR package, but plotting other graphs is fine. I wonder if it is because some dependent packages are missing? It doesn't give me any clue of why R studio crashed. Can any one help?

```
> version                             
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.0                              
year           2022                             
month          04                               
day            22                               
svn rev        82229                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
```

Comment: I suppose the issue comes from rgl as I can't load this required package either. R bombs every time I load rgl package.

Comment: This has a workaround:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72055992/2554330 .