# `rgl` crashes R 4.2.0 in RStudio

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, rgl

The new release of R version 4.2.0 will crash when loading the `rgl` package if in RStudio.  What can I do about it?

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in the startup code that was introduced in 0.100.50 and fixed in release 0.108.3.2.  If you're using a version that has the bug, a workaround is to run `options(rgl.debug = TRUE)` before starting `rgl`.  For example, you could put that line in your `.Rprofile`.

The background was that some Unix systems print spurious error messages on startup, so `rgl` directed those to the nul device.  If you wanted to see them, you could set `options(rgl.debug = TRUE)`. But what's new is that the nul device sometimes fails to open in Windows. `rgl` wasn't checking for that, but now it does.

See  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11043 for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks. I basically stole your answer for the other question you commented on, but I upvoted here so you get some form of credit.

Comment: No problem, that's fine.